# Do any JS implementations currently support (or have support on the roadmap for) fast, vectorized operations on Arrays or similar?

Tags: javascript, vectorization

I'd like to do a bit of matrix/vector arithmetic in JavaScript, and was wondering if any browsers or other JS implementations actually have support for vectorized operations, for instance for quickly summing the entries of two Arrays (or summing, or whatever).  Even if that currently doesn't mean it compiles down to vectorized operations, at least some language support would be nice for when it does get implemented - I'd take the existence of functions or syntax to support it as a step in the right direction.  (Understandably, "vectorization javascript" searches are pretty much all about graphics and SVG.)

Answer (score 0):

I googled for "math vector javascript library" and I came up with http://sylvester.jcoglan.com/ and http://blog.vlad1.com/2010/02/05/mjs-simple-vector-and-matrix-math-for-js/. Does this help?

Comment: No, not really. My question was whether any JS implementations (V8, Spidermonkey, Tracemonkey, Squirrelfish and so on) had support for vectorized operations, natively. mjs and sylvester are just linear algebra libraries - which is cool and all, but that's essentially what I want to write myself. I want to see if any of the JS implementations support vectorized operations so I could do it in a non-boneheaded way.